# How to count the number of nodes in a linked list without traversing it?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have been asked in an interview how to count the number of nodes in a linked list without  traversing the list? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: how about handling it while inserting ?

Comment: yes @Jgar its very obvious answer and that is what i also suggested to interviewer but he did not impress .

Comment: Theoretically (although not practically very relevant) assuming you performed no allocation in your program other than this linked list, you could query the OS for memory consumption difference between now and when the list was empty. Dividing by the size of each element will give the list size. Obviously not as good as just keeping track on insert.

Comment: @Davin  how much practical is it??

Comment: I think, you can give a index to each node if your nodes never change. Ex; for first node, when you construct it, then give a int index = 1, when second one constructed index = 2, ... . While doing this, you can do a any job with O(1) complexity.( including searching, changing its place .. ) . Of course when you look your last node index you can know how many node you have

Comment: I forget to say, of course daynamic allocation is bad because you should store them in vector. ( I thought you know c++, I've answered so )

Comment: @AMIT, in any real program this would be impossible, because you can't really know what other parts will or won't allocate memory, so querying memory consumption will provide you with an upper bound for the list size. How close the upper bound is depends on how much memory your program allocates from the list creation.

Comment: You should've asked the interviewer: "How many coins do I have in my pocket?" :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to add a counter of the number of nodes which is incremented each time the *add* or *insert* methods are invoked, and decremented when *delete* is invoked. You cannot make assumptions about memory occupied because, being a linked list, you cannot guarantee that all nodes will be in the same memory block (indeed, this is highly improbable).

Comment: one thing i would like to know allocation in heap is not contagious??

Comment: Do you mean contiguous? (Sorry, but I just felt strongly confused when first read your comment.) About the heap, you don't even have that as a guarantee. In general, yes, most heap implementations will give you contiguous blocks if they are asked for in secquence. However, due to reallocations, fragmentation, nodes that are not asking for memory in secquence, etc, you cannot assume that they are contiguous in memory.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake ,its contiguous not contagious and I got your point.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing allocation dynamically with something like malloc then there is no way other than updating a counter each time you insert/delete. If you're not doing allocation dynamically then you probably haven't implemented a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

What these other guys are saying is totally right. How can you know how many items are in something before you look at them?

You're going to need to maintain a count, and increment/decrement it on inserts/deletes. It's the (most|only) reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter to your struct and make the linked list circular instead of singly. Instead of traversing through the entire list just traverse to the initial node's prev node.

Comment: How do you insert (or delete) a node in the middle of the list with only a reference to the node the new item is being linked to?