# LinkedList used in an interview's test

Tags: c++, linked-list

[**EDIT**]Fixed my code. Is while(temp != NULL), not while(temp->next != NULL). Sorry to insert wrong code.

Today I've participated an online programming test. The interviewer used Codility to evaluate my code and the other interviewees.
At some moment a question about Linked list was made. It's about to count how many items a linked list has.
I did the only possible approach to do this, AFAIK:

```
//This is struct declaration
struct SomeStruct
{
    int value;
    SomeStruct* next;
}

int elementCount(SomeStruct* list)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(list != NULL)
    {
        SomeStruct* temp = list;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I remember when I send this code as answer for this question, Codility points me out that this solution is wrong because its consume too much time to execute the task.
In my head and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368813/how-to-count-the-number-of-nodes-in-a-linked-list-without-traversing-it) on SO there's no other way to get size of linked list without traversing it, not in a simple way.

Is there a problem with Codility when it says this solution is wrong? Or there are another approaches?

PS: the test allowed using of STL

Comment: You're answer isn't just wrong because of time; its wrong because its off by one. while (temp) is the expression you needed. Case in point: this returns (0) with one element in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you don't have to evaluate the indirection `temp->next` *twice* for each iteration.

you can simply do

```
int count( SomeStruct const* pNode )
{
    int result = 0;
    while( pNode != 0 )
    {
        ++result;
        pNode = pNode->next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Also, as [WhozCraig notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390007/linkedlist-used-in-an-interviews-test/13390046#comment18289242_13390007), your code was logically wrong (yielding an off by one result), not just potentially inefficient.

Comment: I knew that having two `pNode->nex`t was causing an issue, but I couldn't quite put my finger on it...

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Correct. I've written wrong code in my post. I didn't pay attention. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Your solution is incorrect, since it returns 1 less than the actual count. Just try applying it to a list with 1 element.

Why did you come up with this strange two-tiered structure with an `if` and and a cycle that checks `temp->next`? Why not just

```
unsigned elementCount(const SomeStruct *list)
{
  unsigned count = 0;
  for (const SomeStruct *temp = list; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    ++count;
  return count;
}
```

I suspect that you decided to treat the element pointed by the `list` as the unused and reserved "header" element. Indeed, sometimes it might make sense to do implement lists that way. But I see nothing like that stated in your post. Did they tell you to treat it that way specifically?

Comment: @AndreyT No. I chose this approach. For me is the most straight form.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: The point of the temporary is to keep the original parameter value unchanged (i.e. "never use parameters as ordinary local variables"). Some people prefer to follow that convention. I personally don't always follow it. But I see certain logic in it, which is why I usually try to stick to it on SO.

Comment: @learner: My "Did they tell you..." question should be read as "Did they tell you to treat the first element as reserved/unused header element and not include it into the count?"

Comment: @AndreyT Sorry my misunderstanding. The answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Codility may be using a circularly linked list to check, in this case, your code will never end.

Using STL trivilailzes this though, as it has a List<> with a size method.

Comment: a circularly linked list would be quite difficult, and it seems unlikely that someone would spring that on the testee.

Comment: @Jeff Ok, but because of this codility considers the solution wrong. For me is too much.